# Workaround for Implementing Feedback Loops and Retraing in Form Recognizer

Tags: azure-form-recognizer

Does anyone know of any work around of "Retraining" models in Form Recognizer APIs? I understand that Form Recognizer Training APIs create a New model everytime you train a data set. Did some manage to have a workaround to continuously training models?

Answer (score 0):

There is not such workaround. You may delete the old models if you are concerned about number of models grows too fast.

Or do you have other reasons trying to keep using the old model ID?

Comment: hi - the reason is that, as part of the ML concepts, we should keep training and retraining the existing model so that it learns from new training data. It's of limited benefit to create new model for new training data set.

Comment: Hi @Chaz - any luck on this? I do not find anywhere on docs.microsoft to validate/confirm the below scenario. I have 5 documents that I have trained and got the Model Id "AA". Now, I realize that I need newer 5 samples for better accuracy. So I train with these newer sample of 5 docs. It generates model Id "BB". 
Question - is model "BB" trained with only those newer 5 documents or is trained with both - the older 5 & the newer 5? If "only newer 5" is the answer, it would mean that it's altogether a fresh model which got created and totally ignores the previous learning it did. Can you help??

Comment: No. The service doesn't have knowledge that the model shall be incrementally trained based on an old model. 

The service doesn't keep any training data, thus when training the new model, we no longer have access to the old data. 

The suggested practice is to combine the old 5 documents and the new 5 documents and send them together to train a new model. This way the system will learn from all the data. And you can safely delete the old model.

Comment: Thanks a ton @Chaz. This helps. But, somehow the below video keeps talking about "supporting feedback loops and re-training over time" and gives a feel that you can keep doing "incremental" training. But, as I hear from you, it actually doesn't do anything incrementally. Rather it's a always a new beginning with additional training sample. [link]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fo7bAtZYe2o. Any thoughts /views from you?

Comment: The video was a bit brief on re-training capabilities. As the Form Recognizer takes input from files on a blob storage, incremental training here means adding more labeled files into your storage. The Train API will need to see all old/new files to improve the model. 

Incremental training without the old data is an interesting research topic in the future.